# Is there a way to add a custom command line link to a shell script in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a conditional Jenkins pipeline script where stages are executed or skipped depending on parameters. When skipping stages, they also disappear from the stage view which is not what we want.

The parameter relates to either build / start release / finish release of the project.

We tried the release plug-in. However it doesn't support DSL scripted multibranch jobs. We also looked at the "batch command" plugin which has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pipeline is scripted then this

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

def call(boolean condition, body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.OWNER_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    if (condition) {
        body()
    } else {
        Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
    }
}
```

would solve the problem as it would mark the stage as skipped ([jenkins-source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/Utils.groovy)) instead of  making it disappear. But you will have to refactor your code in order to use this. A suggestion on where to place it is a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) as a static call for easy access.

The usage is

```
when(shouldSkip == false) {
  yourStage()
}
```

Comment: This URL explains this method as well. Might help. https://comquent.de/en/skipped-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/

Comment: It is the same thing yes. Did that help you solve the problem?